# Some PHP code is not working, but some can work

Tags: php, curl

I have a question about PHP.
Some of function can run, some can not.

For example

```
<?php
include("LIB_parse.php");
include("LIB_http.php");

# download the page
$web_page = http_get ($target = "http://www.nostarch.com", $referer = "");

$title_incl = return_between($web_page['FILE'], "<title>", "</title>", INCL);

$title_excl = return_between($web_page['FILE'], "<title>", "</title>", EXCL);

echo "title_incl =" .$title_incl;
echo "\n";
echo "title_excl =" .$title_excl;
?>
```

The result is

**title_incl = title_excl =No Starch Press**

My espect is

**title_incl = No Starch Press
title_excl =No Starch Press**

There are two problems in this code.
Firstly, **echo "\n"**; is not working.
Secondly, the included title's spring was not showed.

Another example, parse_array the meta also got problem.

```
<?php
include (\"LIB_parse.php\");
include (\"LIB_http.php\");
#$target = \"https://news.google.com.tw/nwshp?hl=zh-TW&tab=wn\";

$web_page = http_get( $target= \"www.twse.com.tw/ch/index.php\", $regerer = \"\");
$meta_tag_array = parse_array($web_page['FILE'], \"<meta\", \">\");

for($xx = 0; $xx<count($meta_tag_array); $xx++)
    echo $meta_tag_array[$xx].\"\n\";
?>
```

The result is nothing, I expect it should show all meta contents in the console.

I am using Eclipse Luna with PHP plug-in.

Also installed appserv2.5.10

Apache 2.2.8
PHP 5.2.6
MySQL 5.0.51b
phpMyAdmin-2.10.3

Please help. Really thanks.

Comment: When you say `echo "\n";` isn't working, what do you mean? There is no new line? You're going to have to provide the `return_between` function. What is the value of `$web_page['FILE']` before your use `parse_array`. There is so much information missing from this question.

Comment: If you're viewing the result in a browser you will need to look at the source of the page, because browsers will not show `\n` - otherwise output `<br />`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments.
I think some information missing because I using Eclipse to write the code? When I set "run". the result shows on browser. But I didn't see anything on console.

Comment: Hi, I found the problems. I used browser to open the PHP file. That's why the content showed like this. When I used chrome's F12 to see the source code, it got what I want. I didn't install ZendDebugger in Eclipse in previous step, that's why it shows as same as browser.